# Unknown electrical component in circuit - "Chock"

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor

Does "chock" (in the picture) mean inductor with unknown value?

[image]

Comment: Poor translation of Choke?

Comment: Chocks are inserted under wheels to stop vehicles rolling away. Chokes are inductors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choke is like a slang often used for a "really big inductor value" to "choke" ripple voltage by raising the series impedance above LC resonance frequency, shown by the intersection of green arrows for 2 useful values of chokes.

There are many clues to your schematic which show it was done by a nice novice with English as a second lang. (ESL)

The choke inductance value does not mean high current or even low resistance (DCR) so choose wisely.

[image]

So you may find this chart very useful for reading Q and thus resonance amplification for series or parallel RLCf circuits.

So "CHOCK" this one up to experience. I 1st used it in 1975.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a mis-spelling of [choke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(electronics)).

> In electronics, a choke is an inductor used to block higher-frequency while passing direct current (DC) and lower-frequencies of alternating current (AC) in an electrical circuit. A choke usually consists of a coil of insulated wire often wound on a magnetic core, although some consist of a doughnut-shaped "bead" of ferrite material strung on a wire. The choke's impedance increases with frequency. Its low electrical resistance passes both AC and DC with little power loss, but its reactance limits the amount of AC passed.

> The name comes from blocking—"choking"—high frequencies while passing low frequencies. It is a functional name; the name "choke" is used if an inductor is used for blocking or decoupling higher frequencies, but the component is simply called an "inductor" if used in electronic filters or tuned circuits. Inductors designed for use as chokes are usually distinguished by not having the low-loss construction (high Q factor) required in inductors used in tuned circuits and filtering applications.

Source: [Wikipedia Choke (electronics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(electronics)).

[image]

*Figure 1. A [chock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_chock) is a device to hold a wheel or a round object (such as a barrel).*

Comment: I call those wheel stops or wedges. Because if I said chock no one would know what I was talking about, including myself.

Comment: Chocks away biggles. A well know phrase from biggles flies undone.